# XMLReader::next() error stops script

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I'm processing a large (1.2GB) XML file using XMLReader. When it gets to a node with an invalid character in, the script stops running with the error message "Warning: XMLReader::next(): parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !".

Here's a sample script that duplicates the error:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();        
$reader->open('sample.xml',null, LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
while ($reader->read() && $reader->name !== 'item');
while ($reader->name === 'item') {
    $reader->next('item');
}
$reader->close();
```

sample.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<source>
<item>
    <data><![CDATA[good node]]></data>
</item>
<item>
    <data><![CDATA[Suspendisse euismod, ultrices, ligula leo lacinia magna, eleifend fermentum lacus est ut velit! Vestibulum nec magna in tellus mollis fermentum. Mauris vehicula felis eget eros auctor consectetur. Pellentesque imperdiet arcu ac mauris tempor id feugiat mauris commodo. Sed facilisis turpis eu mi ornare tempor. Ut velit erat, volutpat ut sollicitudin et, mattis sed turpis. bad nodé]]></data>
</item>
<item>
    <data><![CDATA[another good node]]></data>
</item>
</source>
```

Is there anyway to either ignore the node and move to the next one, or clean the data to process it?

The XML document is from an external source and I have no control over it and will not be able to change it.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$reader->open('sample.xml',UTF8, LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
```

this may help you

```
  // enable user error handling
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
  /* ... do your XML processing ... */
  $errors = libxml_get_errors();
 foreach ($errors as $error) {
    // handle errors here
 }
 libxml_clear_errors();
```

Comment: Thanks @hiren-soni. That allows me to catch/hide the errors, but it doesn't allow me to move to the next node. So the script still stops when it hits an invalid character. How do I get it to ignore and carry on?